# Assign relationsships to built in users

Tags: python, django

I have created this model in my project

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db import models
from quiz.models import Quiz

# Create your models here.
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, I understand it should be the other way around. I want the user to belong to an organisation.

How can I make this happen? Preferebly not only in the application I created but universally in the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter, care to elaborate why the downvote?

Comment: possibly because the solutions are documented and easy to find ("django extend User" should yield some useful results), which falls under the "this question does'nt show any research effort". (nb : I'm _not_ the downvoter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many to many relationships (ie: if a user can belong to more than one single organisation), all you need is to use a `ManyToManyField` on your own model.

For true one to many relationships (where "user" must have a foreign key on your own model), you'll need to either [extend the `User` model with your own "profile" model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [replace the default `User` model with your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).